# Iterate over elements of columns Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe composed of two Arrays of Doubles. I would like to create a new column that is the result of applying a euclidean distance function to the first two columns, i.e if I had:

```
 A      B 
(1,2)  (1,3)
(2,3)  (3,4)
```

Create:

```
 A      B     C
(1,2)  (1,3)  1
(2,3)  (3,4)  1.4
```

My data schema is:

```
df.schema.foreach(println)
StructField(col1,ArrayType(DoubleType,false),false)
StructField(col2,ArrayType(DoubleType,false),true)
```

Whenever I call this distance function:

```
def distance(xs: Array[Double], ys: Array[Double]) = {
  sqrt((xs zip ys).map { case (x,y) => pow(y - x, 2) }.sum)
}
```

I get a type error:

```
df.withColumn("distances" , distance($"col1",$"col2"))
<console>:68: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: Array[Double]
       ids_with_predictions_centroids3.withColumn("distances" , distance($"col1",$"col2"))
```

I understand I have to iterate over the elements of each column, but I cannot find an explanation of how to do this anywhere. I am very new to Scala programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a custom function on a dataframe you need to define it as an `UDF`. This can be done, for example, as follows:

```
val distance = udf((xs: WrappedArray[Double], ys: WrappedArray[Double]) => {
  math.sqrt((xs zip ys).map { case (x,y) => math.pow(y - x, 2) }.sum)
})

df.withColumn("C", distance($"A", $"B")).show()
```

Note that `WrappedArray` (or `Seq`) need to be used here.

Resulting dataframe:

```
+----------+----------+------------------+
|         A|         B|                 C|
+----------+----------+------------------+
|[1.0, 2.0]|[1.0, 3.0]|               1.0|
|[2.0, 3.0]|[3.0, 4.0]|1.4142135623730951|
+----------+----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

**Spark functions work on column based** and *your only mistake is that you are mixing column and primitives in the function*

And the error message is clear enough which says that you are passing a column in the *distance* function i.e. `$"col1"` and `$"col2"` are *columns* but the *distance* function is defined as `distance(xs: Array[Double], ys: Array[Double])` taking *primitive types*.

The solution is to *make the distance function fully column based* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def distance(xs: Column, ys: Column) = {
  sqrt(pow(ys(0)-xs(0), 2) + pow(ys(1)-xs(1), 2))
}

df.withColumn("distances" , distance($"col1",$"col2")).show(false)
```

which should give you the correct result without errors

```
+------+------+------------------+
|col1  |col2  |distances         |
+------+------+------------------+
|[1, 2]|[1, 3]|1.0               |
|[2, 3]|[3, 4]|1.4142135623730951|
+------+------+------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful